# how does mpi_byte work?

Tags: c, fortran, mpi

I saw a post on Stackoverflow about a simple program with mpi:

[Simple MPI Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945321/simple-mpi-program)

in that program, the user was trying to broadcast a char variable length equal to 20
by using the MPI_BYTE mpi-type instead of MPI_CHAR.

I was trying (probably not very clever) to broad cast an integer variable "n"
using the MPI_BYTE type:

```
call MPI_BCAST(n,1,MPI_BYTE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
```

but I got simply a big number when I print the value of "n" for the processors 
different than the root.

My question is when could I use MPI_BYTE?

I have read that it is machine-architecture dependent but I still don't get the point.

regards.

Comment: I am not an expert, but even in homogeneous systems there is a teorétical difference between BYTE and CHAR is that BYTE doesn't imply any arithmetic operation associated with them. For example, you can Reduce over CHARS but not over BYTES.

Answer (score 9):

Your issue is rather simple to solve: Your use of `MPI_BYTE` is (almost) perfectly fine, however your size/number of elements (in this case: number of bytes) to send is wrong.

Depending on the length of an integer (e.g. 4 bytes), you'd have to set the second parameter to 4:

```
call MPI_BCAST(n,4,MPI_BYTE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
```

Whether you use `MPI_BYTE` or `MPI_CHAR` here won't matter as both are the same length (this is like `unsigned char` vs. `char`). But you have to keep in mind that this won't work between different architectures.

To solve this, use the correct type (`MPI_INTEGER`) to ensure (behind the scenes) conversion, e.g. from little endian to big endian:

```
call MPI_BCAST(n,1,MPI_INTEGER,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason MPI messaging functions ask for the type of the message is so that MPI can perform representation conversion between the source and destination machines. For example, when sending an integer from a machine that uses little-endian number representation to one that uses big-endian, the bits can be rearranged to preserve the original value of the integer.

Using MPI_BYTE will prevent MPI from performing any kind of representation conversion. This can be useful when you want to preserve the exact same bit sequence. I think one use case would be if you stored an array of booleans bit-by-bit (similar to how `std::vector<bool>` does in C++): in that case, you don't want MPI to shuffle bits around.